# Code keeps saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript

My code keeps returning the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null". I can't figure out what it means and I've made many changes to the code to try and fix it without success

```
var speed = prompt("1000 = Fast PC, 500 = Slow PC")
function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";   //changes depending on code variables

  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)   //changes depending on code length
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}


function main() {
    document.getElementById("INPUTBOXNAME").value = makeid(); //INPUTBOXNAME is placeholder
    document.getElementById("SUBMITBUTTONNAME").click(); //SUBMITBUTTONNAME is placeholder
}

setInterval(function() {
    main();
}, speed);
```

Could really appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: There likely doesn't exist an element on the page with an ID of `INPUTBOXNAME` at the time of script execution. Double check that the ID in the html in spelled correctly, and if it is, make sure that the code is being executed after the element has already rendered to the DOM

Comment: try to add a condition `if` to make sure the element exist before setting its value

Comment: So where's your relevant HTML code? Clearly `document.getElementById("INPUTBOXNAME")` is failing, so do you even _have_ an element with `id="INPUTBOXNAME"`?

Comment: The `INPUTBOXNAME` and `SUBMITBUTTONNAME` portion of the code are just used as placeholders that I put there. Since that part of the code will change depending on where I run the code, I only put those there to fill the empty space. The problem is that when I _do_ put something in, the aforementioned error comes up and thats where I need help. I should have clarified that earlier, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("INPUTBOXNAME")` seems to be returning `null` in this case. Therefore, you could start by checking if your markup really has an element with an id equal to `INPUTBOXNAME`. Most probably it will not be the case, or there will be a typo there.

Explanation: This error message means that you are trying to do `null.value = something;` somewhere in your code. To debug this kind of problem, you should look for the places in your code where you are trying to set the `value` property of an object, and think of a reason why that object could possibly be a `null` instead of what was expected.

Comment: Thanks, but the ("INPUTBOXNAME") and ("SUBMITBUTTONNAME") are just placeholder. Since that will change depending on what website I run it on, I just put those names in as a placeholder. And I can't figure out where the null.value is

Comment: Aha, this means you are not running this javascript code on a page which actually has elements with these IDs. That actually is the source of the error. To make this code work - create at least a "dummy" html markup for this script to operate on, and don't forget to add elements with these IDs there. As soon as you do that, your error will disappear.

Comment: That's what I _thought_ the problem could be, but the elements I use are elements selected using the mouse cursor selection tool in Google Chrome. So I guess I'll try what you suggested in repl.it or something

Comment: Okay, let me know what you did and how it went afterwards ;-)